# Nuget Pack conditional compilation symbol

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, conditional-compilation

I would like to be able to package my nuget files with a conditional compilation symbol (`NUGET` or similar) so that I can use a preprocessor directive specifically for my nuget build.

eg

```
#if NUGET 
    [Obsolete("use v2.IMyContract", true)]
#endif
```

Is there some way I can pass this into the `nuget pack MyProject.csproj` command?

#### Why

I have an assembly which contains contracts for a plugin, there are multiple versions of these contracts (.vX. namespaces within the assembly) which need to be built and referenced by the actual implementation for backwards compatibility.

I would like to be able to distribute these contracts with a breaking `[Obsolete(true)]` attribute to force consumers to use the latest version of the contracts when they upgrade their nuget package. However internally I still need to use these objects to maintain my backwards compatibility.